# JSON LInq Query

Tags: json, linq, json.net

I am looking at trying to use a Linq query to determine if the following JSON is true if it contains a product that has a SKU of 12345 OR a TypeCode of "C".

```
"[{\"SKU\":\"12345\",\"Description\":\"Test Part 12345\",\"TypeCode\":\"A\",\"Cost\":24.99},{\"SKU\":\"54567\",\"Description\":\"Test Part 54567\",\"TypeCode\":\"B\",\"Cost\":9.99},{\"SKU\":\"QWZ2342\",\"Description\":\"Test Part QWZ2342\",\"TypeCode\":\"C\",\"Cost\":19.99}]"
```

I have been working with the Json.net (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

At first, you have to deserialize the JSON into a C# object, lets say Product.

```
class Product
{
    public int SKU { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string TypeCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

then, using .NET's JavaScriptSerializer (System.Web.Script.Serialization), convert the json string to become List of your custom objects.

```
string json = "[{\"SKU\":\"12345\",\"Description\":\"Test Part 12345\",\"TypeCode\":\"A\",\"Cost\":24.99},{\"SKU\":\"54567\",\"Description\":\"Test Part 54567\",\"TypeCode\":\"B\",\"Cost\":9.99},{\"SKU\":\"QWZ2342\",\"Description\":\"Test Part QWZ2342\",\"TypeCode\":\"C\",\"Cost\":19.99}]"

JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
productList = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Product>>(json);
```

the last step, using simple linq query, you cant check whether your product exist on the list:

```
var Found = from o in productList
                    where o.SKU == 12345
                    select o.SKU;
if (Found.Count() > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: When I run the linq query I am getting back all results and not what is filtered by the where statement. My List<Products> contains 80 items. When I add a where clause and specify a value that does not exist (such as o.SKU == "ZZZZZ") I still get a var Found that is not null and the count is 80 items.

Comment: I noticed the Sourc count = 80 but the Results View is empty if the query where condition is not true. However, checking if Found != null is is returning true even if the Result View is empty. How might be the best way to determine if the query returned any results?

Comment: Ok I think I have it. I am using the Count() method such as int count = Found.Count();